# Prevent WordPress JS plugin code from running on my WordPress admin pages

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to develop a simple WordPress pop-up plugin for my site, but I can't prevent the "click" for `addEventListener` from running on my admin pages. How do I do that, so  it will only run on my Home and other single pages?

Comment: If you have any code to share or where you think you might need to change something, it may be helpful to the reader who may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The function `is_admin()` in PHP will return "true" for when you're in the admin area, so you could use this to only include your JavaScript file when in the frontend of the website.

So, for example, if you're using WordPress's enqueuing system to include your JavaScript file something like this should work:

```
if (!is_admin()) { // Enqueue when not in the admin area
   wp_enqueue_script("popup", "popup.js");
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/